# Насколько нужны автопрефиксы типа webkit- в сетке bootstrap4

Tags: css, webkit, bootstrap4

Собирала себе болванку для кастомизации сетки bootstrap4. После сравнения с исходником bootstrap-grid.css, увидела, что gulp-autoprefixer (v3.1.1)  не добавляет такие префиксы:

```
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-basis: 0;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 8.33333%;
  -webkit-order: 0;
```

Вопрос: насколько они необходимы, для каких версий браузеров (использовала last 15 versions). И чем их можно добавить?

Answer (score 2):

1) Заходим на сайт [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com), вводим нужное свойство, и смотрим (напр. для `display: flex`)

> Usage
>
> Global 94.53% +   3.55%   =   98.08%
>
> unprefixed 94.23% +   2.72%   =   96.95%

Получаем, что 1.13% браузеров не увидят свойство без префикса

2) Кастомизировать свойства, у меня стоит опция `"> 1%"`, и префиксы проставляются.

Comment: А точно “ > 1%“ стоит? Методом подбора, определила, что префиксы проставляются  при значении >0.1 - 0.2%

Comment: (["last 15 versions","> 1%", "ie 8", "ie 7"], {cascade: true})

Comment: Вот ie8, ie 7 думаю точно лишние. Тем более сам bootsrap4 для ie 10+ .

Comment: И сетка с такими настройками будет отличаться от той что в дистрибутиве. Но в целом информация была полезна, особенно про настройки для автопрефиксера (да, это по нубски, но вот так вот). Но нашла как воспроизвести сетку на 99.9% (напишу ниже) . А там уже по ситуации можно будет настройки автопрефиксера менять.

Answer (score 0):

Для решения подобного вопроса рекомендую пользоваться [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex). В правом верхнем углу есть статистика поддержки свойста с префиксом и без. Мне кажеться что префиксы можно смело неиспользовать, так как они нужны только для около 1% пользователей.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге хоть в чем-то ответы и были полезны, все же сама поняла, как можно сделать. По поводу автопрефиксов – для каких версий и какие – это у каждого свои предпочтения, у [DiDex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/259580/didex) , если исключить ie7,8 , - отличный вариант. Но вот для того, чтобы сделать сетку как в исходном дистрибутиве bootsrap4 (v4.0.0) , для postcss+autoprefixer (именно так, gulp-autoprefixer на «>=» ругается)  нужны такие настройки:

```
postcss([ autoprefixer({
            browsers: [
                "last 1 major version",
                ">= 1%",
                "Chrome >= 45",
                "Firefox >= 38",
                "Edge >= 12",
                "Explorer >= 10",
                "iOS >= 9",
                "Safari >= 9",
                "Android >= 4.3",
                "Opera >= 30"
            ],
            cascade: false
        }) ])
```

В общем-то, это из package.json разве что взят Android не 4.4, а 4.3 . В итоге отличие лишь в цифрах округления 33.333333% > 33.33333%